# From Git to SVN: Failed to merge in the changes

Tags: svn, git

I have some code in a Git repository that needs to be synchronized with a SVN repository. My recipe looks like this:

1. Create a SVN repository (local, for testing, will be a remote one).
2. Create initial layout, commit 1 revision
3. `git svn clone -T '/trunk' <REPO>` a new Git repository based on the initial commit.
4. `git remote add dev <ORIGINAL>` followed by a `git pull dev <ORIGINAL_BRANCH>`. Now I have my master branch in the repository based on the initial SVN commit.
5. `git svn rebase` which would be followed by `dcommit`.

Step 5) however fails with:

```
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging X
Applying: Y
Applying: Z
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:269: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:315: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:400: trailing whitespace.
     * Method 2.6. Returns zero or two elements 
<stdin>:3762: trailing whitespace.

warning: 4 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
```

Followed by a couple of "Auto-merging" and "CONFLICT (content)" messages the rebase finally halts with a friendly "Failed to merge in the changes". Is there anything I can do to have these conflicts resolved automatically? I do not even understand how conflicts can occur when rebasing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving up and use `set-tree` instead. A `git rebase -p` results in a history with the artificial git-svn initial commit at root, followed by the initial commit from the original Git repository...

For completeness my references for the three approaches tried:

1. http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit - `git rebase`
2. http://markpasc.livejournal.com/186297.html - `git svn rebase`
3. http://repo.or.cz/w/nagiosplugins.git?a=blob;f=tools/git2svn.pl - `set-tree`

Answer (score 3):

Conflicts are conflicts, and git can't ever really resolve them for you. Only a human can say for sure which of two mutually exclusive modifications is the right one.

As for why you can get conflicts during a rebase? It's really the same kind of operation as a merge, just resulting in different history. Suppose you rebase commit X onto commit D here:

```
- A - B - C - D
   \
    X
```

The resulting content should be the same as if you merged D into X. If there's something in commit B which conflicts with a change made in commit X, there are going to be merge conflicts. It doesn't matter whether you're merging or rebasing.

Comment: But how can conflicts occur when I rebase to a single commit which merely adds three directories (the SVN standard layout)?

Comment: @yawn: Well, what are the conflicts? You must be rebasing some content.

Comment: I think the conflicts result from previous merges - something along that rebase might clash with merges that were resolved with a commit?

Comment: @yawn: `git-rebase` by default doesn't preserve merges. See the man page, and the `-p` option.